# No permission to webspace after changing webspace key

Tags: sulu

I am new to [Sulu](https://sulu.io/) and trying to learn using it for a new project. After playling around a bit I wanted to change the platform key.

After that, the admin interface didn't show the *Webspaces* tab anymore.

I executed the commands

- bin/console ca:cl
- bin/adminconsole ca:cl
- bin/adminconsole sulu:build dev
- bin/adminconsole sulu:webspaces:init
- bin/adminconsole sulu:content:validate:webspaces

But nothing helped. After some debugging I found out that the new webspace was initialized, but my admin user did not get the new permissions.

Looking in the database I found some entries still related to the old webspace key in the `se_permissions` table:

| id | context | module | permissions | idRoles |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | sulu.webspaces..default-snippets | 127 | 1 |  |
| 9 | sulu.webspaces. | 127 | 1 |  |
| 10 | sulu.webspaces..analytics | 127 | 1 |  |
| 11 | sulu.webspaces..custom-urls | 127 | 1 |  |

Is there a way to automatically update the permissions? Is it a bug in Sulu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug. Renaming a "webspace key" will lose all your connected data to it. Including that your role have permissionf for it.

Mostly a webspace key rename happens only on development.

If you have no data to loose you can go with (attention remove all existing data in your configured database):

```
bin/console sulu:build dev --destroy
```

Else a new or renamed webspace need to be added to your user role that you can see it. Go to `Settings` -> `User Roles` and give your role permissions for your new webspace / renamed webspace.

[image: Add Webspace permissions to your Role]

If you change a webspace key of a production website you would normally need to create database migrations. So you are not losing any pages, permissions, ... or other things connected to the webspace key.